# CSC Kahler metrics on a blown-up torus

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, kahler-manifolds, kahler-einstein-metric

Let $T$ be a compact torus, and $X$ its blow-up 
in a point (or in several points). It seems that 
$X$ is K-stable for any Kahler form on $X$. 
Is there a reference to this?

Also, what can  we say about the
constant scalar curvature Kahler 
metrics on this blow-up? Do they 
exist in all Kahler classes?
They do exist in some Kahler 
classes, by the famous result of 
Arezzo and Pacard:

Claudio Arezzo and Frank Pacard,
Blowing up and desingularizing constant scalar curvature Kähler manifolds,
Acta Math. Volume 196, Number 2 (2006), 179-228.

If I am right and the standard conjectures
about K-stability are true, it seems that 
the CSC Kahler metrics should exist for 
all Kahler classes.

Answer (score 2):

This statement about blow ups of torus is not correct. Take any aglebraic $2$-torus with a smooth curve $C$ of genus $>1$. Blow up $C^2+1$ points on $C$ and apply Theorem 1 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.4078.pdf

Comment: and what if the torus is non-algebraic?

Comment: For the application I have in mind, non-algebraic tori are more than sufficient

Comment: I would bet that no positive result in this direction that is stronger than Arezzo-Pacard is known. I would guess (but this is only a guess) that using Theorem 1.2 here https://arxiv.org/pdf/0807.1716.pdf one could construct example similar to what I gave you by making an iterated blow up of a non-algebraic torus. This would lead to appearance of quite "bad" divisors there, composed of rational curves. But probably you should ask experts like Yuji Odaka, or Gabor Szekelyhidi